# Operands of type Object used for '&'; runtime errors could occur

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, debugging

When I set my code behind as "STRICT" (Option Strict On), I get the following error: *Operands of type Object used for '&'; runtime errors could occur*.

Here's the problematic line:

```
dataSet.Sort = CType(ViewState("sortExp") & DESCENDING, String)
```

Just wanted to know what's wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Are you missing `"` around `DESCENDING`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewState("sortExp")` returns an `object`. With `&` you try to concatenate `DESCENDING` (which I assume is a string.) In strict mode this is not allowed. Try this:

```
dataSet.Sort = ViewState("sortExp").ToString() & DESCENDING
```